# How to start intent inside custom Listadapter which extends ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

I want to start a new activity to send sms to some number. I have tried this code but my activity crashes. I get null NullPointerException. Guide me how to start new activity kindly. I have also added permission for sms in manifest file

```
  public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParseUser> {
private  Context context;
public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ParseUser> user1) {
    super(context, resource, user1);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, null);
    }

    final ParseUser p = (ParseUser) getItem(position);

    if(p!=null){
        TextView username = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.username);
        TextView bloodType = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.bloodtype);
        //TextView longitude = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.longitude);
        //TextView latitude = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        //TextView mobile = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.mobile);
        Button msgButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.message_me);
        final String number = p.getString("Mobile");

        if(username!=null){
            username.setText(p.getString("Name"));
        }
        if(bloodType!=null){
            bloodType.setText(p.getString("Bloodtype"));
        }

        msgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent a = new Intent(getContext(),SmsActivity.class);
                a.putExtra("number",number);
                context.startActivity(a);

            }
        });
    }



    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide your LOGCAT

Comment: I think the issue is in this line "Intent a = new Intent(getContext(),SmsActivity.class);" "getContext()" should be replace by "context"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here: `context.startActivity(a);`. You are using `context` field but never assign it. You can assign it in the constructor:

```
public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ParseUser> user1) {
    super(context, resource, user1);
    this.context = context;
}
```

Or you can use `getContext()` instead of `context`: `getContext().startActivity(a);`. In this case you don't need `context` field completely.

Answer (score 0):

can you replace to this

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent a = new Intent(this.ListAdapter ,SmsActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent a = new Intent(getContext(),SmsActivity.class);
```

change to

```
 Intent a = new Intent(context,SmsActivity.class);
```